# How to use `numpy.hstack()` with `numpy.ndarray` data type?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have a `numpy.DataFrame` say `df` with 3 columns, `col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`. Data in `col_1` are  `numpy.ndarray` and looks like this: `array([ 0.216, -0.290,  0.349])`

How could I use np.hstack() to expand the `DataFrame` with columns consist of each data point in `col_1`?

i.e.
**Original DataFrame**

```
                     col_1   col_2               col_3
------------------------------------------------------
0   [0.216, -0.290, 0.349]  NORMAL  N09_M07_F10_K001_1
```

**Supposed DataFrame**

```
                 col_3  col_2     0      1     2
------------------------------------------------
0   N09_M07_F10_K001_1 NORMAL 0.216 -0.290 0.349
```

I'd tried like this:

```
Supposed_DataFrame = pd.concat(
    [df[['label', 'filename']], 
     pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(df["signal"].values).T)
    ], 
    axis=1)
```

but the output was:

```
                 col_3  col_2     0
-----------------------------------
0   N09_M07_F10_K001_1 NORMAL 0.216
```

any simpler solutions will be appreciated

Comment: look for some sort of pandas 'explode'.  This is a pandas task, not a numpy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out this code:**

```
import pandas as pd

dict_ = {
    'col_1': [[0.216, -0.290, 0.349]],
    'col_2': 'NORMAL',
    'col_3': 'N09_M07_F10_K001_1'
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

supposed_DataFrame = pd.concat([df2[['col_3', 'col_2']], pd.DataFrame(df2['col_1'].to_list(), columns=[0,1,2])], axis=1)
print (supposed_DataFrame)
```

**Method-2** : using basic steps:

```
row_1 = df2['col_1'][0]
for i in range(len(row_1)):
    df2[i] = row_1[i]

df2.drop('col_1', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df2)
```

Comment: thanks, I used your **Method-2** and no longer need np.hstack()